# How would I make an announcement go to the mentioned channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How would I make it so you can say `;announce #channel message`? So instead of sending it in the channel you wrote the message in, it sends it to the channel you mentioned?

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + `announce`)) {
  if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
    let split = args.split("-");
    let url = args[2];
    message.channel.sendMessage("@everyone", {
      embed: {
        color: 0xFFFF00,
        title: "New Announcement!",
        description: split[0],
        url: split[1],
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
          icon_url: message.author.avatarURL,
          text: message.author.username
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) includes every mention in the message, and its property [`.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=channels) gives you every channel mentioned.
Knowing that you can get the channel from the mentions, then remove it from the arguments.

Here's an example:

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + `announce`)) {
  if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
    // I've added this part
    let channel = message.mentions.channels.first(); // you get the first mentioned channel
    if (!channel) return message.reply("No channel mentioned."); // if it doesn't exist, you exit
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(" "); // if it exist, you remove the command AND the channel

    let split = args.split("-");
    let url = args[2];
    channel.sendMessage("@everyone", { // here you send it to your channel instead of the same one
      embed: {
        color: 0xFFFF00,
        title: "New Announcement!",
        description: split[0],
        url: split[1],
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
          icon_url: message.author.avatarURL,
          text: message.author.username
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```